# Como converter em utf8 uma string com caracteres especias?

Tags: flutter, dart

> Não estou conseguindo decodificar os caracteres que aparecem nessa
>   string com o Dart.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main(){

var myString="Data de coleta superior &amp;agrave; 15 dias n&amp;atilde;o permitida.";

var newString = utf8.decode(myString);

print(newString);   //Retorno desejado: Data de coleta superior há 15 dias não é permitida.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o package `dart:html` para fazer o que deseja, consegui reproduzir o que você deseja removendo os `&amp`, veja se minha solução te ajuda.

Uma outra coisa é que sua String estava com alguns códigos errados de acordo com o resultado que espera... Corrigi para:

```
"Data de coleta superior h&aacute; 15 dias n&atilde;o &eacute permitida."
```

---

Segue um exemplo de como ficou o código:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

void main(){

  var myString="Data de coleta superior h&aacute; 15 dias n&atilde;o &eacute permitida.";

  print(_parseHtmlString(myString));
}

String _parseHtmlString(String htmlString) {
  var text = html.Element.span()..appendHtml(htmlString);
  return text.innerText;
}
```

*Você pode testar aqui no [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/).*

*Fonte: [Decode HTML encoded text in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61141254/10145630).*